# Splitting Input But Inserting Into Array

Tags: java

The user types in something like: @!#$%^, 123. I know that I can split the two with `.split(", ")`, but I want to be able to put both the @!#$%^ and 123 into arrays, so that later I will have `{@, !, #, $, %, ^}` and `{1, 2, 3}`. Are there any ways to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After splitting you will get String array with 2 elements.

```
stringarray[0].toCharArray() , stringarray[1].toCharArray() //returns all characters as a char array.
```

is what you are looking for.

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun I'm scared. I don't want to be Paul :(

Answer (score 1):

Do like this

```
    String a="@!#$%^, 123";
    String[]b=a.split(",");
    char[]c1=b[0].toCharArray();
    char[]c2=b[1].toCharArray();
    System.out.println(c1);
    System.out.println(c2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the two strings with the comma first, but then you will have to be a little more cunning to get `{@, !, #, $, %, ^}` and `{1, 2, 3}`.

```
String[] s1 = "@!#$%^, 123".split(","); //after this line, s1 will have two elements
char[] a = s1[0].toCharArray(); // this converts a string to a char array
char[] b = s1[1].toCharArray();
```

After the code executes, `a` will contain `{'@', '!', '#', '$', '%', '^'}`, notice that the elements are all character literals instead of strings. Array `b` will contain `{'1', '2', '3'}`, also character literals.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String s="#$%*1,123";
        String str[]=s.split(",");
        char ar1[]=str[0].toCharArray();
        char ar2[]=str[1].toCharArray();

        for(int x=0;x<ar1.length;x++){
            System.out.println("arr1 data "+ar1[x]);
        }

        for (int y=0;y<ar2.length;y++){
            System.out.println("arr2 data "+ar2[y]);
        }

    }
```

> Output :-

```
arr1 data #
arr1 data $
arr1 data %
arr1 data *
arr1 data 1
arr2 data 1
arr2 data 2
arr2 data 3
```

[More split method here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)